# Trying to install gdl-coyote on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to install gdl-coyote on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installe gdl using the command apt-get install gnudatalanguages. Which installs version 9.4

I have downloaded the gdl-coyote_2016.01.14-1_all.deb package and get the error it wont install due to dependencies of gnudatalanguages (> 9.5) has not been met.

I am uncomfortable trying to compile my either an updated version of gdl, or a lower version of gdl-coyote.I am still trying to fix my computer after the last bad install.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers
Andrew

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for the question; however, FYI for clarification, the gdl install command is singular: apt-get install gnudatalanguage